# Notation regarding integral w.r.t. a measure

Tags: probability, notation

While reading articles about statistical inference and SMC algorithms I have come by the following notation (never seen in school) to represent the expectation w.r.t. a measure $\mu$

$$
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)] = \int\phi(x) \mu(\text{d}x),
$$

which I have come to understand means

$$
\int\phi(x) \text{d}\mu(x), \text{ or }  \int\phi(x) \mu'(x)\text{d}x.
$$

However, when defining the empirical measure $\mu_N(\text{d}x)$

$$
\mu_N(\text{d}x) := \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}\delta_{X^i}(\text{d}x),
$$

does the notation

$$
\text{d}\delta_{X^i}(x)
$$

make any sense? Or can we just use notation

$$
\delta_{X^i}(x)\text{d}x
$$
in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I have ever seen the notations $d\delta_{X^i}(x)$ or $\delta_{X^i}(x)dx$. However the former seems correct to me, as $d\mu(x)$ is a common notation. But I don't really like the latter, as it seems to imply that there's a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, which is of course wrong.

If I had to define the empirical measure, I would just write:
$$\mu_N=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N\delta_{X^i}$$
which perfectly makes sense and is unambiguous.

When I'm writing an integral I prefer to use the notation $\int f(x)d\mu(x)$, or simply $\int fd\mu$, rather than $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$, but both notations exist and I think it's just a matter of habit

Comment: That was my thought as well, wanted to check with the experts before using the notation however. Thanks for the input! Cannot upvote your answer I'm afraid...

Comment: If it comes to notation of integrals then the comments on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/879527/75923) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link @drhab!