# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" 6.1 : Definition of Expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

What does the item highlighted in the definition mean ?

[image]

This looks like the "probability of a random variable" ? if so I am unsure as to what this means ...

Comment: I suspect that here $P(f)$ is used as a notation for $\int fdP$. Also see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879527/75923).